# Cognito not sending verification SMS to iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I've set up Cognito and ensured that SNS limits are in place.

Verification SMS is being sent to Android phones, however, it's not being sent to iPhones.

The CloudWatch logs show the SMS was successfully sent.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK SMSs are platform agnostic. You shouldn't have this problem based on OS. It could more likely be related to limits itself. Sometimes AWS uses resources from a different region for SMS delivery which is not the region your services are running. e.g. if your service is deployed in ap-south-1 then AWS uses ap-southeast-1 (Singapore) for SMS delivery. You need to make sure if both the regions have appropriate limits available.

It is also worth checking your carrier settings and phone spam block settings.

Comment: I've requested for limits under Singapore to check if this resolves the issue

Comment: Singapore limits were set and moved to production but the problem still persists